# Is it possible to supply a default value to a Text widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

As the question states, I would like to supply a default value to a Text Widget. I have four Text widgets. I use a variable in each Text Widget to display data. There is a chance that some data may not exist depending on the user and I would like to be able to default these Text Widgets to 0 if the value doesn't exist to prevent an error. Is this possible? Thanks!

Below is how it is currently.

```
                                Text(
                                  '\$${quarter['data'][0].funds}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a default value using the `??` operator, which returns the expression on its left unless that expression’s value is null, in which case it evaluates and returns the expression on its right (and you might need to add question marks for conditional property access in case `quarter['data']` and `quarter['data'][0]` are nullable):

```dart
Text(
  '\$${quarter['data']?[0]?.funds ?? 0}',
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
)
```

To safely access the funds at an index of the `quarter['data']` list, you can create a helper method:

```dart
int fundsAt(int index) {
  // This will return 0 if no element exists at the given index
  return index >= 0 && index < quarter['data'].length
    ? quarter['data'][index].funds
    : 0;
}
```

Here is the example of using `fundsAt()`:

```dart
Text(
  '\$${fundsAt(0)}',
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
)
```

Comment: The issue with this I'm attempting to get around is it throws a range error as soon as it hits a text widget where the data doesn't exist since there may not be a quarter['data'][1].funds. There may be only a quarter['data'][0].funds and so forth. I figured it would have been null but I suppose not.

Comment: What I understand from what you said is that `quarter['data']` returns a list of objects and it throws a range error because the index you provide doesn't exist in the list. Please, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :
`'\$${quarter['data'][0].funds ?? 0}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

If the value can be null, then you can try this:

```
Text(myNullableData ?? "Default value");
Text(myNullableData == null ? "" : "Default value");
```

The `??` operator use your value if it is not null. If yes, it will use the default value you want.

Otherwise if `some data may not exist depending` means that the variable can be just an empty string: '""', then you can use the `?:` operator:

```
Text(myData == "" ? "Default value" : myData);
```